# DetailView redirect when object DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have started working on converting some old code that uses function based views to try to use class based views where applicable. I have the below class that grabs a profile object based on a set of parameters. My questions is if I get a `DoesNotExist` error I want to redirect to a specific url in my application. How would I go about that?

```
class ProfileView(generic.DetailView):
model = Profile
template_name = 'area51/profile.html'

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return Profile.objects.get(**self.kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `get` method. Catch the `Http404` and redirect to the required URL.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404

class ProfileView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'area51/profile.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(ProfileView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            return redirect('/profile-does-not-exist/')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, **self.kwargs)
```

Note that I've used `get_object_or_404` which will raise `Http404` instead of `DoesNotExist` error. This is to be consistent with the [`DetailView.get_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a5a2ceeb453b86caaf01687342984f372428beb8/django/views/generic/detail.py#L20) method.

Comment: Great that works, thank you! Would it make more sense to keep it how I had in a function view since the code is shorter? Similar to this: https://gist.github.com/justinrsmith/cfb06a724b99fbc8a201c02571334b26

Comment: The function based view is simple and easy to understand. If you’re happy with it, stick with it.